# Best way to search for date availability in lucene

Tags: lucene, date-range

I have a scenario in which I have an object which has an availability property assosiated with it. I have encoded the dates in a month as a 32 bit binary with 1 for available and 0 for not available. Now I want to search for objects that are available on a range of dates. How will I best do it with lucene?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way to store that would be as:

```
available_on=20111028
available_on=20111029
```

where the date is encoded as an integer, and one field for each date that is available. Then you can use a NumericRangeQuery to search the availability range.

Failing that, I guess you could write a filter to step through each value used for your bitfield and pick out the ones with one of the requisite bits set.

Comment: I was thinking about the filter part. Is it a good method? When implementing former method you will have too many entries, right? So if it is completely available in the month of October you will have 31 entries. Is that a good approach?

Comment: that nr of values in a multivalued field really is no problem.. You will probably filterquery (FQ) on date as well, and with only that nr of distinct values availabilities are cached real fast.  Just make sure you only need to have availability info, and not some data (like pricing) related to each of the availability-dates.

Comment: Filtering happens before indexing right.. SO how can it be of use in my search in this particular case? or can we add custom search methods?